# Use Alt-Space key combination on gVim

Tags: vim, key-bindings

I have problems using Alt-Space in gVim (v7.4) running on Linux  (Linux Mint, Cinnamon).

Pressing Alt-Space will only show a Â character (0xC2) on the bottom line and it seems you have to press another key after to return to initial state.

It is even stranger considering I'm able to use/remap Alt-Space correctly under Windows and, while on Linux, other applications are able too (by the way: I disabled the Desktop Environment default shortcut for Alt-Space, which opens the current Window menu, so the key combination is not prematurely intercepted).

I have found this discussion which presents the same situation of mine, but no results.

[unable to map   < M-space >](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/unable-to-map-lt-M-Space-gt-td4428150.html)

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

PS simply remapping the character Â was not helpful.

Comment: Remapping that accented character worked or not?

Comment: Do you use gvim, or terminal vim?

Comment: Remapping the accented character did not work.
I use gVim, but having it working on Vim on terminal would be very nice too.

Comment: I have still no answer to this, but I add this comment to present a (unrelated?) work-around which let me abandon the need for using <A-Space> mapping. I have found on the Internet the (great IMO) gem advice by someone of using <Space> as leaderkey in Vim, and this led me to change some of my mappings towards this new approach.

Comment: I think you should consider using neovim which takes full advantage of unibilium and libtermkey, althought it's young and does not have a GUI.

Comment: Yes, neovim should be fine, thank you.

Comment: By the way, when stuck on gVim: rather than leaving the `Alt-Space` combination unused, I found an alternative usage which is satisfactory for me: instead of remapping the shortcut at gVim-level, I remapped it at DesktopEnvironment level (using xdotool on Linux or AutoHotKeys on Windows OS) to perform something useful. For example I'm currently using  `Alt-Space` to show/hide (like a pop-up console) the gVim window.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered remapping the "Â" character to execute the command you want to execute? It's sort of hacky, but it might work in this one environment (could be a problem if you share your vimrc with other machines)

for instance, on a previous machine (mac), i had this:

```
:nmap π :CtrlP<return>
```

so that i could type option+p (which renders a "π") in order to execute :CtrlP

like i said, a hack - but a working hack.

Comment: Hi. Yes I tried it (copied straight the 'accented A' char and put it in the vimrc file) but no results for me.

Comment: Did you also add the
    <return>
bit?